# How do I draw gridlines using grid() behind the plot?

Tags: r, plot, gridlines

My code is:

```
plot(series,xlab="Tempo",ylab="Participação em %",ylim=c(10,55),type="s")
grid()
```

which yields:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that there is an easy way of drawing these gridlines behind the plot, but I couldn't find any in the grid() documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `panel.first` argument in `plot`:

```
plot(1:50, 1:50, xlab="Tempo",ylab="Participação em %",ylim=c(10,55), 
     type="s", panel.first=grid())
```

[image]

A hackier way, if we didn't have `panel.first` would be: Run the plot code, but use `type="n"`, which will prevent the data from being plotted. Add the grid. Then use `lines()` to plot the data on top of the grid.

```
plot(1:50, 1:50, xlab="Tempo",ylab="Participação em %",ylim=c(10,55), type="n")
grid()
lines(1:50, 1:50, type="s")
```